# characterizing clusters after k means analysis in r

Tags: r, statistical-significance, multivariate-analysis

I did a k-means cluster on a data set which looks at how well individuals scored on a test (y variable) given varying difficulty (x variable). I then started looking at the demographics of the individuals. These demographics were not considered in the cluster analysis--think location, age, gender. I started researching the "accepted" way to statistically analyze these demographics to see if these clusters had interesting, significant factors amongst them. One method I saw is finding the centroid of the cluster and going from there, but this does not quite make sense to me, as this is a huge dataset and picking the person in the middle of each cluster wouldn't be informative when considering the demographics that weren't part of the original cluster analysis. I think it is interesting, but not informative.

I did a graph of these demographics for each cluster, and to the blind eye there does seem to be differences in demographics among each cluster. I'm looking dig into this, preferably with multivariate analysis, but I am getting stuck on the best way to do this.

Comment: Are your observations the individuals? If so, how is the "difficulty" a variable characterising an individual?

Comment: The difficulty is the difficulty of the test that was given to the individual, which was somewhat "unique" to each individual. It was a general description of what I was working on, not exact, but I understand that I could have explained it better. I more so gave this detail to imply the demographics were not considered in the cluster analysis, only two separate factors were, and now I'm trying to understand how the demographics relate to the clusters, if at all. But, in summary, both variables in the original cluster analysis did relate to the individuals.

Comment: Why not regress the demographic data against the (nominal) cluster identifiers?  You could do this graphically, in an exploratory manner, or even with formal testing (ANOVA or MANOVA or loglinear modeling *etc.*) using standard tools.

Comment: @whuber If you mean to look at the demographic information for each cluster graphically and compare the clusters, I've done that, and I think it may be interesting. I would like to do some formal testing like you mentioned, but I've been having trouble because I have categorical variables for my clusters, and I would like to see which variables are significant when compared to their proportions in other clusters. I've looked for similar analysis and come up short, so I was hoping there was a key phrase for this analysis I was missing that I could research more.

Comment: Your description sounds like a standard ANOVA.

Comment: I feel pretty goofy... This seems like the way to go... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would graphically look at the distribution of any variable of interest within the different clusters. Maybe that's what you did already. The centroid is only informative regarding the variables used for clustering.

Comment: I did do that, if I'm understanding you correctly, and it looked pretty interesting. For example, a specific cluster , lets say "cluster 1" was mostly female, another lets say "cluster 2" was about equal in males and females. Other demographic features, like location, didn't seem to differ much among the clusters. The graph was great for me to look at, but I'm looking for a way to mathematically "prove" it in a way that makes sense. I've been trying multivariate analysis, but keep getting stuck on how to do it correctly while considering the clusters.

Comment: I also agree about the centroid issue. I saw it recommended on a very similar thread as I was doing my due diligence to be sure this question wasn't already answered elsewhere. I assume there are nice ways of doing what I'm trying to do, but I'm fuzzy on my statistics.